# Standardizing API error responses in Laravel (API Resources)

Tags: php, laravel, json-api

Working on a new repo. After doing some research, I've decided to use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources) to standardize my API responses, according to [jsonapi.org](https://jsonapi.org/) best practices.

I am not able to get a good answer on the best way to return consistent user-readable [error messages](https://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects-basics) (not exceptions). These are messages that can potentially be returned directly from the controller. Using Laravel's API Resources, I've been able to create something like this, but it feels hacky.

```php
$error = (object) (['errorCode' => 422, "messageDetail" => ["First name must contain at least three characters."]]);
return  new ErrorResource($error);
```

`ErrorResource` is used to format the JSON in this case. The thinking is that whenever a developer wants to code up an error message, that they would use `ErrorResource`.

Is there is a better way?

Comment: write logic in base controller and extend basecontroller in controller so you may use like `parent::parentmethod($params);`

Answer (score 1):

inside `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` you can change render function as per your requirement and return the Resource from this function. Here is an example

```
   public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->is('api/*') || $request->expectsJson() || $request->is('webhook/*')) {


         $error = (object) (['errorCode' => 422, "messageDetail" => ["First name must contain at least three characters."]]);

         return  new ErrorResource($error);

    }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);



}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me better do error formatting in app/Exceptions/Handler.php:render.

This is a more flexible approach and helps to do it in one place.